# How to deposit testcoin in peatio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, bitcoin, bitcoind

I cloned [peatio](https://github.com/peatio/peatio) project, I run the server locally my question is how to deposit my test-coins in peatio and my test-coin address is `mtV5o3VMNMfjHqma3kvLauUSVPRUyr6giM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how can you get some test coins, google 'bitcoin testnet faucet'.

If you mean how to make the coins sent to you add to your account balance in database:

1. Make sure you set `walletnotify` option in `.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`. For example:

   ```
   walletnotify=curl http://localhost:3000/payment_transaction/btc/%s
   ```

   With this a new PaymentTransaction will be created on new received coins.
2. Make sure you've run `rake daemons:start`. It will start a coin deposit daemon to process every PaymentTransaction created in previous step. Check `lib/daemons/coin_deposits.rb` for more details.

Comment: Hey @Jan I 've added this in my bitcoin.conf file. But It is not able to find the route. 
Server trace:
Started GET "/payment_transaction/btc/669940435a4b9046146ce61d85513a00f6e9e09def2f89ef21913fbdf14d098d" for 192.168.1.41 at 2017-10-26 14:07:28 +0530